# Probability of picking a the first $n$ digits from a number in the Vitali set

Tags: probability, measure-theory, asymptotics

Consider a [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set#Construction_and_proof), $V$, that only contains numbers with a unique decimal notation.

We define $P_k(V)$ as the probability that, when picking a random sequence of $k$ digits, there is a $v \in V$ whose decimal notation begins with those $k$ digits. Since their are only finitely many $k$ digit sequences, this is well defined for any $k \ge 0$.

Note that $\lim_{k \to \infty} P_k(S)$ is equal to the measure of $S$ if $S$ is measurable, I think.

My question is, what is the behavior of the function $f(k)=P_k(V)$. Also, does this behavior change is use a base other than base ten?